# phpMyEdit knows the records are there - they're just not displaying

Tags: mysql, database, records

So I've successfully gone through all the necessary steps as stated in the README file for phpMyEdit. The final result is supposed to display here:

http://torbaybusroutes.co.uk/fleet/index.php

But as can be seen, although it's certain there are 147 records, it doesn't want to display any of them.

Anyone got any ideas as to why?

Thank you in advance.

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<head><title>TBR :: MyRoute Search</title></head>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="main">
  <h3>Torbay Fleetlist</h3>
<?php
//  MySQL host name, user name, password, database, and table to edit
$opts["hn"] = "removed";
$opts["un"] = "removed";
$opts["pw"] = "removed";
$opts["db"] = "removed";
$opts["tb"] = "removed";

// Name of field which is the unique key
$opts["key"] = "id";

// Type of key field (int/real/string/date etc)
$opts["key_type"] = "int";
// Initial field to sort on
$opts["sort_field"] = "id";

// Number of records to display on the screen
// Note value of -1 lists all records in a table.
$opts['inc'] = 15;

// Options you wish to give the users
// A(dd) C(hange) (co)P(y) V(iew) D(elete) F(ilter) I(nitial sort suppressed)
$opts['options'] = 'ACPVDF';

// Number of lines to display on multiple selection filters
$opts['multiple'] = '4';

// Number of lines to display on multiple selection filters
//$opts['default_sort_columns'] = array('pushId','due','priority','task');

// Navigation style: B - buttons (default), T - text links, G - graphic links
// Buttons position: U - up, D - down (default)
$opts['navigation'] = 'DB';

// Display special page elements
$opts['display'] = array(
    'query' => false,
    'sort'  => false,
    'time'  => false
    );

/*
    Field definitions. Fields will be displayed left to right
    on the screen in the order in which they appear in this list.
    ['name'] is the title used for column headings, etc.;
    ['sort'] = true means the users may sort the display on this column;
    ['type'] is generated by SETUP.php and indicates the mysql field type
        best not edited
    ['maxlen'] maximum length to display add/edit/search input boxes
    ['trimlen'] maximum length of string content to display in row listing
        if strlen(value) > trimlen, display substr(,0,trimlen-3).'...'
    ['width'] is an optional display width specification for the column,
        e.g.  ['width'] = '100px';
        or $fdd['colname']['width'] = ($fdd['colname']['trimlen'] * 8).'px';
    ['nowrap'] true or false.  whether this field should get a NOWRAP
    ['mask'] a string that is used by sprintf() to format field output
    ['datemask'] a string that is used by date() to format date fields
        see PHP's date() for valid formatting characters
    ['daterange'] a  of numbers
        ['daterange']['start'] = 1996;
        ['daterange']['end']   = $fdd['colname']['daterange']['start']+20;
    ['URL'] is used to make a field 'clickable' in the display, e.g.:
        ['URL'] = 'mailto:$value' or ['URL'] = 'http://$value';
        ['URL'] = '$page?stuff';
        Note that the following are available as variables:
            $key    key field for record
            $name   name of the field
            $value  value of the field
            $page   this HTML page
            $urlstr all page variables
            $row    mysql_fetch_assoc() for this row
        ['URLtarget']  HTML target link specification (for example: _blank)
        ['URLdisp']    what to display as hypertext link (by default $value)
        ['URLprefix']  old 3.5 ['URL'] behaviour, will prepend string before
        ['URLpostfix'] similary to ['URLprefix'] will append string after
    ['required'] = true will generate javascript to prevent null entries by users
    ['options'] is an optional parameter to control whether a field is
        displayed in the A(dd), C(hange), D(elete), view, or L(ist) views
        ['options']='R' indicates that a field is read only
        ['options']='P' indicates that a field is a password field
        ['options']='H' indicates that a field is to be hidden
        and marked as hidden
    ['textarea']['rows'] and/or ['textarea']['cols'] specifies a
    textarea is to be used to give multi-line input,
        e.g. ['textarea']['rows'] = 5; ['textarea']['cols'] = 10
    ['values'] restricts user input to the specified constants,
        e.g. ['values'] = array('A','B','C')
        or   ['values'] = range(1,99);
    ['values']['table'] and ['values']['column'] restricts user
        input to the values found in the specified column of another table.
        The optional ['values']['description'] field allows the value(s) displayed
        to the user to be different to those in the ['values']['column'] field.
        This is useful for giving more meaning to column values.  There are two main
        options when using the ['values']['description'] field. These are whether you
        want to use a single, or multiple field in your description.  To apply single,
        you need to use:
            ['values']['description'] = 'desc_column'
        This may be used, with no other options, and will simply display the description
        for the corresponding value.
        For Multiple, use:
            ['values']['description']['columns']['1'] = 'desc_column_1'
            ['values']['description']['divs']['1']    = ' '
            ['values']['description']['columns']['2'] = 'desc_column_2'
        The 'div' component is what will be used as a divider between the columns
        in the display.  You don't need to define the last 'div' field if it isn't
        required.  So, for example...if you have a series of people in a
        table, with a separate column for id, first name, and last name, you could
        use:
            ['values']['db']='mydb' *optional if table is in another database*
            ['values']['table']='mytable'
            ['values']['column']='id'
            ['values']['description']['columns']['1']='name_last'
            ['values']['description']['divs']['1']   =', '
            ['values']['description']['columns']['2']='name_first'
            ['values']['filters']='idcolumn in (1,2,3)' *optional WHERE clause*
            ['values']['orderby']='last_name' *optional ORDER BY clause*
        if a column is either SET or ENUM type, then the values are put in 
        by PME Setup.
    ['select'] = 'T/D/M' (text, drop-down, or multiple selection for filters)
        if a column is a SET type, then this is automatically 'M'
    Calculated Expressions
        example:
            $fdd['other']['name']='Col Header';
            $fdd['other']['expression']='onHand-ordered';
            $fdd['other']['sort']='T:!';
            $fdd['other']['select']='T';
            $fdd['other']['type']='int';
        'other' can be anything, but needs to be unique within the list of $fdd keys
        'expression' can be any valid MySQL expression
        'type' should reflect the results of the expression, e.g. 'int' or 'string'
        all other options work as with other, normal columns
        this kind of column is always read-only
*/
$fdd["id"] = array(
    'name'=>'ID',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'int',
    'maxlen'=>6,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Operator"] = array(
    'name'=>'Operator',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Fleet number"] = array(
    'name'=>'Fleet number',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Year"] = array(
    'name'=>'Year',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'int',
    'maxlen'=>4,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Registration"] = array(
    'name'=>'Registration',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>10,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Chassis"] = array(
    'name'=>'Chassis',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Bodywork"] = array(
    'name'=>'Bodywork',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Depot"] = array(
    'name'=>'Depot',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Allocated to"] = array(
    'name'=>'Allocated to',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Branding"] = array(
    'name'=>'Branding',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Name"] = array(
    'name'=>'Name',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);

$fdd["Low floor?"] = array(
    'name'=>'Low floor?',
    'select'=>'T',
    'type'=>'string',
    'maxlen'=>100,
    'nowrap'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
    'sort'=>true
);



$opts['fdd'] = $fdd;

/* Table-level filter capability (if set, is included in the WHERE clause of any
   generated SELECT statement; this gives you ability to wirk only with subset of
   data from table)

   Some valid examples:
     $opts['filters'] = "column1 like '%11%' AND column2<17";
     $opts['filters'] = "section_id = 9";
     $opts['filters'] = "Table0.sessions_count > 200";
 */

/*
Triggers are files that are included (via require) that perform
actions (before or after) X (inserts, updates, or deletes).

'before' triggers are usually used to verify conditions prior to
executing the main operation.

'after' triggers are usually used to perform follow-on operations
after the main operation.  For example, to update secondary tables
to enforce referential integrity or to update aggregate tables.

The operation sequence is this:  before, main, after.  If any
operation fails, not only should the next operation(s) not be
executed, but the previous ones are 'rolled back' as if they
never happened.  If a database is not able to do this, it is
not 'transaction-safe'.

Triggers are risky in basic MySQL as there is no native transaction
support--it is not transaction-safe by default.  There are
transaction-safe table types in MySQL that can be conditionally built
(see MySQL-Max), but phpMyEdit is currently not set up to support real
transactions.  What that means is that if an operation fails, the
database may be left in an intermediate and invalid state. 

The programmer must understand and accept these risks prior to using
the phpMyEdit triggers mechanism.

If the triggers are used, they execute within the namespace or scope
of the phpMyEdit class.

They _must_ return true or false to indicate success or failure.
*/

/*
$opts['triggers']['insert']['before']='.TIB.inc';
$opts['triggers']['insert']['after'] ='.TIA.inc';
$opts['triggers']['update']['before']='.TUB.inc';
$opts['triggers']['update']['after'] ='.TUA.inc';
$opts['triggers']['delete']['before']='.TDB.inc';
$opts['triggers']['delete']['after'] ='.TDA.inc';
*/

/* Logtable schema

CREATE TABLE changelog (
  updated timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  user varchar(50) default NULL,
  host varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  operation varchar(50) default NULL,
  tab varchar(50) default NULL,
  rowkey varchar(255) default NULL,
  col varchar(255) default NULL,
  oldval blob,
  newval blob
);

$opts['logtable']= 'changelog';
*/


/* Get the user's default language and use it if possible or you can specify
   language particular one you want to use. Available languages are:
   DE EN-US EN FR IT NL PG SK SP */
$opts['language']= $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

//  and now the all-important call to phpMyEdit
//  warning - beware of case-sensitive operating systems!
require_once '../fleet/scripts/phpMyEdit.class.php';

$MyForm = new phpMyEdit($opts);

?>

  </div>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: any code to show? pretty pictures don't help much in figuring out problems like this.

Comment: Code now added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest you re-run phpMyEditSetup.php. If it runs successfully, it will generate a script that will display the table as long as your mysql database connect credentials are correct, the setup script will not complete if it isn't anyway. I'm a new user to phpmyedit but i must say I've had no problems so far. If your still having problems, please send me an SQL dump of your table and I'll see if I can create the script at my end.

Answer (score 0):

might be **accents** problem -

in PHP 5.4 the default encoding used by htmlspecialchars() was changed. To fix the same problem in our site, I did the following:

1. Replace each `'htmlspecialchars(...)'` 
   with 
   `'fhtmlspecialchars(...)'`
2. Add the function 'fhtmlspecialchars':

   `function fhtmlspecialchars($myString) { 
   // in PHP 5.4 the default encoding used by htmlspecialchars() was changed. 
   return htmlspecialchars($myString, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1', true); 
   }`

[based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php + Dave's comment there]

similiar problm on phpMyEdit site:

- http://opensource.platon.sk/forum/projects/viewtopic.php?t=10785766